# RoleArn not accessible for ECS Role in CDK

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

In the following code snippet, I am getting the error while building the project. Eventhough I have defined ecs service some lines above the usage, why is the role being shown as undefined ?

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'roleArn' of undefined
```

I can see that roleArn is an accessible field of Role. what am I doing wrong here ?

```
    let ecsService: FargateStack;
    
    .... (lines of code)

    const service = target.serviceDefinition;
    const serviceName = generateResourceName(service.shortName, stageName, airportCode, account, cell);
    ecsService = new FargateStack(app, serviceName, {
      softwareType: SoftwareType.LONG_RUNNING_SERVICE,
      ...(other params)
      httpsListener: cluster.httpsListner,
    });
    ecsService.addDependency(cluster);
    servicesStacks.push(ecsService);

    if (!awsAccountsWithOpenSearchCreated.has(accountRegion) && ecsService.serviceName == ServiceName.CONFIG_STORE){
      const openSearchStackName = generateResourceName('opensearch', stageName, airportCode, account, cell);
      const openSearchStack = new OpenSearchStack(app, openSearchStackName, {
        env: deploymentEnvironment,
        ... (other params)
        role: ecsService.role.roleArn
      });
      regionalResources.push(openSearchStack);

    }
```

FargateStack is defined like given below and is initialized in the constructor

```
export class FargateServiceStack extends DeploymentStack {
  public readonly role: Role;

  public readonly alarms: Alarm[];

  .....(lines of code)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `ecsService` variable is of type `FargateStack`.  It presumably extends `cdk.Stack`, which has no `role` property.

You are probably looking for the role on `ecs.[Fargate | Ec2 ]Service`'s [task definition](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_ecs.TaskDefinition.html). If so, expose the ECS Service as a [public instance field](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Public_class_fields#public_instance_fields) in `FargateStack`:

```js
// FargateStack.ts
export class FargateStack extends cdk.Stack {
  readonly service: ecs.FargateService;

  constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props: MyFargateStackProps) {
    // ... code ...
    this.service = new ecs.FargateService(...)
```

The role is available on the service's task definition:

```js
const { service } = new FargateStack(...)

const role: iam.Role = service.taskDefinition.taskRole
```